Draw a graph on vertices inputted as "A"+ 2 "B", 3"A" + 4"B", etc (the input form is imposed) in Euclidean space, with A->(1,0), B->(0,1)
I have  a Mathematica script, called FHJ, with four main arguments: vertices, edges, weights of edges, groups of vertices, which produces a graph with vertice labels given in the list vertices,  coloured and shaped differently, according to specified groups, and edges labels given in weights. A last optional argument specifies the size of vertices.
FHJ[comp_List, edges_List, rates_List, groups_List : {},ver_:.45] :=
  Module[{colorList, shapeList, vertexColors, options, vertexShapes, 
    defaultColor = Yellow},
   colorList = {Green, Red, Yellow, Purple, Orange};
   shapeList = {"Square", "Circle", "ConcaveHexagon", "Triangle", 
     "Hexagon", "Pentagon", "Star"};
   vertexColors = 
    Join[Flatten[
      MapIndexed[Thread[#1 -> colorList[[#2[[1]]]]] &, groups]],
     # -> defaultColor & /@ Complement[comp, Flatten[groups]]];
   vertexShapes = 
    Flatten[MapIndexed[Thread[#1 -> shapeList[[#2[[1]]]]] &, groups]];
   options = {VertexShapeFunction -> vertexShapes, 
     VertexStyle -> vertexColors, VertexSize->ver,
     VertexLabels -> {_ -> Placed[Automatic, Center]}, 
     EdgeStyle -> {{Black, Thick}},
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
     EdgeLabels -> Thread[edges -> rates], 
     EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Background -> White]};
   LayeredGraphPlot[edges(*, Right*), options]];

See for example the output of
vert={"B","A",2 "A"+"B","A"+2 "B"};
edg={"B"->"A",2 "A"+"B"->"A"+2 "B"};
wei={Subscript[k, 1] Subscript[x, B],Subscript[k, 2] \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(A\), \(2\)]\) Subscript[x, B]};
FHJ[vert,edg,wei,{{"A","B"}},.35]

Now in the case when, like above, the vertices are formal sums of two letters, I would like  a numerical conversion of the vert to
vertn={{0,1},{1,0},{2,1},{1,2}} (this should be done maybe in a separate script) and then a modification of the FHJ graph so that its vertices are represented  at the vectors given in vertn (maybe giving up centering)
I have managed to get the 2 scripts, but only if I impose the letters to be "A","B" (that's OK), and if I change the inputs instead of 2"A" +"B" to "2 A + B" (and I'm only able to convert between the inputs by manual tweaking). Here are the two scripts:
convNum[vertices_List] := Module[
  {basis, processTerm, parseVertex},

  (* Define basis vectors for A and B *)
  basis = Association[{"A" -> {1, 0}, "B" -> {0, 1}}];

  (* Function to process each term and convert to vector *)
  processTerm[term_] := Module[{coef, letter},
    (* Extract coefficient and letter, default coefficient is 1 if missing *)
    {coef, letter} = 
     StringCases[term, {a : DigitCharacter .. ~~ " " ~~ l : ("A" | "B") :> {ToExpression[a], l}, 
                        l : ("A" | "B") :> {1, l}}][[1]];
    coef * basis[letter]
  ];

  (* Parse each vertex string into terms and sum the resulting vectors *)
  parseVertex[vertex_String] := 
   Total[processTerm /@ StringSplit[vertex, " + "]];

  (* Apply the conversion to the entire list of vertices *)
  parseVertex /@ vertices
]



FHJn[comp_List, edges_List, rates_List, groups_List : {},  ver_ : .20] := 
  Module[{colorList, shapeList, vertn,vertexColors, options, vertexShapes, defaultColor = Yellow},
  vert=comp;
  vertn = convNum[comp]; 
   (* Color and shape lists *)
   colorList = {Green, Red, Yellow, Purple, Orange};
   shapeList = {"Square", "Circle", "ConcaveHexagon", "Triangle", "Hexagon", "Pentagon", "Star"};
   
   (* Assign colors and shapes to vertices based on groups *)
   vertexColors = Join[
     Flatten[MapIndexed[Thread[#1 -> colorList[[#2[[1]]]]] &, groups]], 
     # -> defaultColor & /@ Complement[comp, Flatten[groups]]
   ];
   
   vertexShapes = Flatten[MapIndexed[Thread[#1 -> shapeList[[#2[[1]]]]] &, groups]];
 (* Ensure that comp and vertn have the same length and can be threaded *)
   If[Length[vert] =!= Length[vertn],
     Print["Error: Length of vertices (comp) and coordinates (vertn) must be the same."];
     Return[$Failed]
   ];

   (* Define graph options with provided vertex positions *)
   options = {
     VertexCoordinates -> Thread[comp -> vertn], (* Use provided vertex coordinates *)
     VertexShapeFunction -> vertexShapes,
     VertexStyle -> vertexColors, 
     VertexSize -> ver,
     VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Center],
     EdgeStyle -> {{Black, Thick}},
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
     EdgeLabels -> Thread[edges -> rates], 
     EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Background -> White]
   };
   
   (* Plot the graph using provided vertex positions *)
   Graph[comp, edges, options]  
   
]

(* Example usage *)
vert = {"B", "A", "2 A + B", "A + 2 B"};
vertn = convNum[vert]
edg = {"B" -> "A", "2 A + B" -> "A + 2 B"};
wei = {k1, k2};

FHJn[vert, edg, wei, {{"A", "B"}},  .20]


You mean: want to place the vertex m A + n B at $(m,n)$ ? Which form do you want to use as vertex, 2"A"+3"B" or "2A+3B" ?

Yes.  Either form is fine, since @Michael E2 gave me a way # /. r_Rule :> ToString /@ r & to convert first form to second.  (It would also be handy to have the opposite conversion)

How about this?
Clear["Global`*"];

FHJ[comp_List, edges_List, rates_List, groups_List : {}, ver_ : .45] :=
   Module[{colorList, shapeList, vertexColors, options, vertexShapes, 
    vertexCoordinates, defaultColor = Yellow},
   colorList = {Green, Red, Yellow, Purple, Orange};
   shapeList = {"Square", "Circle", "ConcaveHexagon", "Triangle", 
     "Hexagon", "Pentagon", "Star"};
   vertexColors = 
    Join[Flatten[
      MapIndexed[Thread[#1 -> colorList[[#2[[1]]]]] &, 
       groups]], # -> defaultColor & /@ 
      Complement[comp, Flatten[groups]]];
   vertexShapes = 
    Flatten[MapIndexed[Thread[#1 -> shapeList[[#2[[1]]]]] &, 
      groups]];
   vertexCoordinates = # -> (# /. {"A" -> {1, 0}, "B" -> {0, 1}}) & /@
      comp;
   options = {VertexShapeFunction -> vertexShapes, 
     VertexStyle -> vertexColors, VertexSize -> ver, 
     VertexLabels -> {_ -> Placed[Automatic, Center]}, 
     EdgeStyle -> {{Black, Thick}}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
     EdgeLabels -> Thread[edges -> rates], 
     EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Background -> White], 
     VertexCoordinates -> vertexCoordinates};
   Graph[edges(*,Right*), options]
   ];

vert = {"B", "A", 2 "A" + "B", "A" + 2 "B"};
edg = {"B" -> "A", 2 "A" + "B" -> "A" + 2 "B"};
wei = {Subscript[k, 1] Subscript[x, B], Subscript[k, 2] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(A\), \(2\)]\) Subscript[x, B]};
FHJ[vert, edg, wei, {{"A", "B"}}, .35]



It works! Except that if I want to use other base letters, say K,L, I need to input them myself in vertexCoordinates = # -> (# /. {"K" -> {1, 0}, "L" -> {0, 1}}) & /@
comp

@florin Yes, you are right. What are base letters and how many base letters are there are problem dependent. There is little merit (at least for me r(^_^; ) to deal with such cases.

Indeed!  In fact for now there will always be two letters, so they might as well be A,B.  But  I was dreaming for the future to  consider problems with more letters, and then plot some two dimensional section. But, for that, one would need first to translate some subnetworks so that in projection the components do not cross each other, and the theory for that doesn't even exist. So you are right, for now, this is precisely what is needed!

@florin Higher dimensional case can be very complicated --- in general, graph is not planar any more. In the case of three base letters, you can specify 3D coordinates in Graph[] and you can look at the shape by turning it around.
